# Error SSL handling exception java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 64 with JDK 1.4.2_19

Tags: java, security, ssl, jsse

Before all, I can't update my prehistoric JDK, it's impossible. 
I have to use JDK 1.4.2_19 because it's the most recent JDK supported by Weblogic 8.1 on non-solaris platforms, and I can't update the application server (an upgrade or a migration would be too much expensive).

So i am trying to establish an SSL connexion with the following code (it's just a test class) under JDK 1.4.2_19 :

```
System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", proxyHost);
System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", ""+proxyPort);
URL url = new URL (request);
SSLServerSocketFactory ssf = (SSLServerSocketFactory)SSLServerSocketFactory.getDefault();
SSLServerSocket ss = (SSLServerSocket)ssf.createServerSocket();

SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
context.init(null, trustManager, new SecureRandom()); // bypass certificate

SSLSocketFactory sf = context.getSocketFactory();
HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sf);

HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();

connection.setSSLSocketFactory(sf);
connection.setHostnameVerifier(new TrustAllHostNameVerifier ()); // bypass certificate

connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
connection.setDoOutput(true);
InputStream content = (InputStream)connection.getInputStream();
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (content));
String line;
while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

This code produce the following error :

```
main, handling exception: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 64
main, SEND TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, description = internal_error
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Alert, length = 2
main, called closeSocket()
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 64
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.a(DashoA12275)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.a(DashoA12275)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.a(DashoA12275)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.a(DashoA12275)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.b(DashoA12275)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(DashoA12275)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(DashoA12275)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(DashoA12275)
    at     sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:620)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(DashoA12275)
    at xxx.test(TestJava14.java:162)
    at xxx.TestJava14.main(TestJava14.java:85)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 64
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SunJSSE_bf.a(DashoA12275)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SunJSSE_bf.a(DashoA12275)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SunJSSE_ax.a(DashoA12275)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SunJSSE_ax.c(DashoA12275)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SunJSSE_ax.a(DashoA12275)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SunJSSE_az.a(DashoA12275)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SunJSSE_az.a(DashoA12275)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SunJSSE_ax.a(DashoA12275)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.a(DashoA12275)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.j(DashoA12275)
    ... 8 more
```

After many hours of research on this error, I tried without success to :

- Use BouncyCastleProvider with the code 
  Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
  and in java.security with
  security.provider.2=org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider
- Use ibmjsseprovider from an old WAS Server (lib ibmjsseprovider2.jar)
  security.provider.2=com.ibm.jsse2.IBMJSSEProvider2 but can't be used with a sun JDK, I get the exception : IBMJSSEProvider2 Build-Level: -20040601
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Export restriction: SunJSSE only
- Disable DHE algorithms in java.security : 
  jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=DHE
- Force a cipher suite that should be working (the unlimited policy files are successfully installed) :
  String[] cipherSuites = {"TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA"};
  ss.setEnabledCipherSuites(cipherSuites);
  (in fact I also tried all the cipher suites availables in the JSSE Ref guide http://depinfo.u-bourgogne.fr/doc/j2sdk-1.4.3/guide/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html)

Comment: You are using SSL with a trust manager that ignored the origin of the server certificate and the `TrustAllHostNameVerifier`. This is **identical** to plain test. Just drop the pretence of security and use plain HTTP. It's this sort of irresponsible coding that gives the internet a bad name.

Comment: Further, even if you were to fix these issues, the list of ciphers [supported by JSSE 1.4](http://download.oracle.com/otn_hosted_doc/jdeveloper/904preview/jdk14doc/docs/guide/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html) is rather ... sparse. Of those, none are considered secure and none will be allowed by a modern, secure, SSL enabled server. `SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA` is literally the only cipher can could be considered remotely secure and even then it doesn't offer [PFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_secrecy).

Comment: I totally agree Boris but it is just a test class for che moment, and I have to connect to an external HTTPS webservice with Basic authentification  without client certificate, it's not my choice. The cipher you suggest is not functionning either, still the same error. Are you telling me there is no solution ? JDK 1.4 supports only TLSv1, if the remote server needs TLSv1.2 i am stuck...

Comment: Could you not get the CA of the other server and install it into your keystore? Does the other server's certificate not match it's hostname? If not, why not? Could you output the [full list of ciphers supported by your JSSE version](https://confluence.atlassian.com/stashkb/files/679609085/679772359/1/1414093373406/Ciphers.java)? Could you use a tool like [SSL Labs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/) or [sslyze](https://github.com/iSECPartners/sslyze) to output the full list of cipher supported by the server? Is there an overlap?

Comment: @BoristheSpider: 1.4.**2** added some decent ciphersuites, as per the link in the Q. But for DHE, j4 (and up through j7) limit the size to 1024 bits, which may be too little for a post-Snowden post-Logjam server. Ben: jdk.tls.disabledAlgoriths is j7+ only, and setEnabledCiphersuites on an SSLServerSocket is completely unrelated to the socket used for HttpsURLConnection; instead use property https.ciphersuites per your link. But I doubt DHE causes this error anyway. ...

Comment: ... I would consider punting on getting ancient Java to handle this and send your request as HTTP through a proxy that converts it to modern HTTPS (like squid, varnish, haproxy, nginx, or apache) or over a TCP-to-TLS relay (stunnel).

Comment: Thank you very much dave_thomson & Boris I just had the line dave suggested to set properly the cipherSuite with the cipher suite suggested by Boris and it's working : System.setProperty("https.cipherSuites", "SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA");
So the problem is linked to DHE suites, because the suite SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA fails. I will now adapt the code to filter DHE suites programatically, as dave said the java.security setting has no effect.
Thank you again to both of you, you saved my day.

Comment: @Ben Is `SSL_RSA` is working `SSL_DHE_DSS` **cannot** work - a server's certificate is _either_ RSA _or_ DSS...

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 HTTP through a decent local proxy is an excellent idea. Doesn't quite answer why the OP is removing all server certificate validation however.

Comment: @BoristheSpider: not entirely; a server _can_ have multiple certificates for different PK algorithms, and send the one suitable for the selected ciphersuite. For example with different ClientHellos I can get both ECDSA and RSA certs from `google.com:443` (74.125.22.several) -- but NOT `www.google.com:443` (172.217.4.several).